# How should I make my discord bot welcome somebody?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm creating my discord bot in discord.py and came across this one problem that I've been trying to solve. I want my bot to make a custom welcome to whomever joins the server. My code so far:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(ctx, member):
    id = client.get_guild(x)
    general = client.get_channel(x)
    
    if discord.on_member_join:
        general.send(f"{member.mention} has joined the server!")
```

VS code is giving me an error at discord saying: *Module 'discord' has no 'on_member_join' memberpylint(no-member)*

Two questions:

1. How do I achieve what I initially wanted - sending the message in the channel that I've obtained the ID of?
2. Why does it give me that error (for my better understanding)?

PS: Hidden the client ID's just to be safe, dunno if it matters, but better safe than sorry! And I'm also new to discord.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
@client.event  #Event to detect when a user joins
async def on_member_join(member):
    general = client.get_channel(id)    #Where id is the channel's ID
    await general.send(member.mention + ' has joined the server!')
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! I tried your code, and it didn't give me any error, but when I run it and join the server with my alt, I get this error in the terminal:



Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\saket\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\saket\.vscode\PythonBots\bruh_bot.py", line 115, in on_member_join
    await general.send(member.mention + ' has joined the server!')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Comment: Hi, I fixed it myself. Looks like _id = client.get_guild(x)_, "x" should have the server ID, and then general has the channel ID. Everything else was perfect and honestly dunno why I didn't think of this myself. Thanks for the help :D

Comment: @hurb, sorry I made a mistake. You don't need `get_guild()` at all. I forgot to remove it after copying your code. I've edited my answer.

Comment: yeah, I saw that. Thanks for helping me